# weird behavior of #undef

Tags: c++, precompile, undef

```
#include <iostream>

#define MY_CONST 10

#define MY_OTHER_CONST MY_CONST

#undef MY_CONST

int main() {

  enum my_enum : int {

    MY_CONST = 100
  };

  std::cout << MY_OTHER_CONST;

  return 0;

}
```

I would expect `10` as an output, but this program outputs `100`. Can someone explain what is going on here?

https://godbolt.org/z/77EedG11x

Comment: Macros are expanded lazily. The compiler doesn't look at the definition of `MY_OTHER_CONST` until you try to use it outside of a `#define`.

Comment: `MY_OTHER_CONST` isn't expanded until you hit `std::cout << MY_OTHER_CONST` and at that point the `MY_CONST` is #undeffed.

Comment: You can just run the preprocessor on your source file to see what the file looks at after preprocessing.  `gcc -E foo.cpp` for gcc.

Comment: undef practically always spells trouble. I recommend to supersticiously avoid it. If you think you need it for something, it is time to redesign. Even the widely used X-macros can be done without.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#define MY_OTHER_CONST MY_CONST` defines the macro `MY_OTHER_CONST` to have a replacement list of `MY_CONST`. No replacement is performed when defining a macro.

In `std::cout << MY_OTHER_CONST;`, `MY_OTHER_CONST` is replaced by its replacement list, becoming `MY_CONST`. At this point, there is no macro definition for `MY_CONST`, so no further replacement is performed. Then `MY_CONST` refers to the `enum` constant `MY_CONST`, which has value 100.

Comment: Is there a way to save the value of `MY_CONST` macro and then `#undef MY_CONST`? Because I need this specific name for other uses

Comment: If you have a name conflict solve it differently. There is a duplicate on that, if you don't mind an upvoted answer by me on it.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174589/undef-seems-to-have-no-effect-on-macro-redefinitions-warning-c4005 There are some variations, also with duplicates.

Comment: @user3600124 In C++ you only need macros in some rather specific situations. They can usually be replaced by C++ core language features. In particular for defining constants they are completely unnecessary. Declare your constants as `constexpr auto` variables in appropriate namespaces instead.

Comment: I am using some old-school C library, where those `#define`'s are used